# flask-bcrypt check_password_hash value always returns false

Tags: mysql, postgresql, authentication, flask, render

I have created a simple flask authentication app

I have deployed it on render with a postgresql service

The app runs fine locally where I use mysql.

But when in the deployed app, the check_password_hash always returns false

The code works fine locally but it fails when i deploy it on render

I tried changing bcrypt to werkzeug, i checked all the versions on the deployment environment

Registration view

```
# Registration route
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form["username"]
        # print(username)-debug
        password = request.form["password"]
        # bytes_register = password.encode("utf-8")
        # print(password)-debug

        # create_table_query_mysql = """
        #     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        #         id SMALLINT(5) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        #         username CHAR(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        #         pass_hash CHAR(128) NOT NULL
        #     )
        # """

        create_table_query_postgresql = """
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                username CHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                password_hash CHAR(255) NOT NULL
            )
        """

        existing_user_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=%s"
        existing_user_username = None

        cursor = connection_db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(create_table_query_postgresql)

        cursor.execute(existing_user_query, (username,))
        existing_user_username = cursor.fetchone()

        if existing_user_username:
            error_message = "Username taken. Please choose a different username"
            return render_template("register.html", error_message=error_message)

        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)
        decoded_hashd_password = hashed_password.decode("utf-8")

        insert_user_query = (
            "INSERT INTO users (username, password_hash) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        )
        cursor.execute(insert_user_query, (username, decoded_hashd_password))
        connection_db.commit()
        return render_template("registration_success.html")

    return render_template("register.html")
```

Login view

```
# Login Route
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username_login = request.form["username"]
        password_login = request.form["password"]
        # bytes_login = password_login.encode("utf-8")

        # create_table_query_mysql = """
        #     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        #         id SMALLINT(5) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        #         username CHAR(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        #         pass_hash CHAR(128) NOT NULL
        #     )
        # """

        create_table_query_postgresql = """
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                username CHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                password_hash CHAR(255) NOT NULL
            )
        """

        user_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=%s"
        user_data = None

        cursor = connection_db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(create_table_query_postgresql)
        cursor.execute(user_query, (username_login,))
        user_data = cursor.fetchone()
        hash = user_data[2]
        print(hash)
        print(password_login)
        # hash_bytes = hash.encode("utf-8")
        # print(hash_bytes)
        check = bcrypt.check_password_hash(hash, password_login)
        print(check)

        if user_data and check:
            user = User(id=user_data[0], username=user_data[1])
            login_user(user)
            return redirect("/dashboard")
        else:
            not_valid = "Invalid User"
            return render_template("login.html", not_valid=not_valid)

    return render_template("login.html")
```

The error causing part is in the login route

```
       cursor.execute(user_query, (username_login,))
        user_data = cursor.fetchone()
        hash = user_data[2]
        print(hash)
        print(password_login)
        # hash_bytes = hash.encode("utf-8")
        # print(hash_bytes)
        check = bcrypt.check_password_hash(hash, password_login)
        print(check)
```

Comment: Please add the complete error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in my code arises from the use of `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` data types. In MySQL and PostgreSQL databases, the `CHAR` type, when defined with a fixed length, behaves differently. MySQL removes padding spaces when retrieving data from `CHAR` fields, whereas PostgreSQL returns the string with padding spaces intact.

The result of this discrepancy becomes evident when working with functions like `check_password_hash()`. For instance, if the password hash is stored in a `CHAR` field and retrieved from PostgreSQL, the padding spaces are not visible in the console, but they affect string comparison. As a result, when `check_password_hash()` compares the hashed password (with padding spaces) to the input, it returns false.

MySQL handles padding spaces differently; while they are present in storage, they are removed during retrieval, leading to consistent behavior with functions like `check_password_hash()`.

In my case, my local environment used MySQL, which explained why the code worked correctly locally but failed when deployed to a PostgreSQL database.

To ensure consistent behavior across databases, it's advisable to use the `VARCHAR` data type instead of `CHAR`. This change eliminates the issue of trailing spaces and ensures accurate string comparison regardless of the database system.

Answer (score 0):

The error you’re encountering is coming mainly from your registration view, I can see that you inserted the `decoded_hashd_password` into the database. This in turn causes the error because there is no hash to check against when you run `check = bcrypt.check_password_hash(hash, password_login)`. Try inserting just the `hashed_password` and not `decoded_hashd_password`.